# SUM of Multiple columns of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

This is tbl_user:

```
-----------------
ID    | Username
-----------------
1       user one
2       user two
```

This is tbl_x1:

```
-------------------------
ID    | User_id | Sum
-------------------------
1       1         10
2       1         20
3       2         30
```

This is tbl_x2:

```
-------------------------
ID    | User_id | Sum
-------------------------
1       1         10
2       1         20
3       1         30
```

This is tbl_y:

```
-------------------------
ID    | User_id | Days
-------------------------
1       1         10
```

I want to select sum(x1.sum + x2.sum) and sum(y.Days).
In other words, **I want the following result:**

```
-------------------------------------
ID    |  Username  |  Sum  |  Days
-------------------------------------
1       user one        90     10
2       user two        30     0
```

I tried with this code:

```
select u.id as ID, u.username as Username, sum(y.days) as Days,(ifnull(sum( x1.sum), 0) + ifnull(sum( x2.sum), 0)) as Sum from tbl_user u left join tbl_x1 x1 on u.id = x1.user_id left join tbl_x2 g on u.id = x2.user_id left join tbl_y y on u.id = y.user_id group by u.id
```

But i get the wrong result.

Comment: And the question is? Where are you stuck? Do you get errors?

Comment: The query doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `join` operation multiplies rows for a given `user_id`.  By multiplying the rows (called a "cartesian product"), you are getting the wrong sums.

The solution is to do the aggregation *before* doing the joins:

```
select u.id as ID, u.username as Username, y.days,
       coalesce(x1.sum, 0) + coalesce(x2.sum, 0)) as Sum
from tbl_user u left join
     (select x1.user_id, sum(x1.sum) as sum
      from tbl_x1 x1
      group by x1.user_id
     ) x1
     on u.id = x1.user_id left join
     (select x2.user_id, sum(x.sum) as sum
      from tbl_x2 x2
      group by x2.user_id
     ) x2
     on u.id = x2.user_id left join
     (select y.user_id, sum(y2.days) as days
      from tbl_y y
      group by y.user_id
     ) y
     on u.id = y.user_id;
```

Comment: is it possible to reach same result with simple joins by dividing the sum to number of repeats of duplicate values while joining multiple tables!?

Comment: Now, I want to write a statement. for example: (WHERE sum - days < 10) but is wrong.What is the correct way?

Comment: @Farhęg . . . That might work with one join, but with multiple joins it would get rather complicated.

Comment: @Garme . . . In MySQL, you can use a `having` clause for that expression.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the reply. I was trying to not use subqueries and write a query with only joins and only one group by, by dividing sum of sums to count of repeats. but didn't get expected result,  that's why I asked that. thanks again and kind regards.